# QuickBooks QBES13 - INTERNAL ERROR WHEN PROCESSING THE QBXML REQUEST

Tags: quickbooks

QuickBooks customers are getting various errors including
`INTERNAL ERROR WHEN PROCESSING THE QBXML REQUEST`

This was from a program that was running for over a year.

Happened as soon as the customer went to QBES13.

Other customers getting various QuickBooks crashes and also
QBXML components were not installed.  (again on programs running for months).

The QBSDKLog got filled with:

```
20130701.150236 E   12504   InvoiceStorage::BuildTheRetObject   This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks. HRESULT=0x80040527
20130701.150236 E   12504   InvoiceStorage::BuildInvoiceLine    This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks. HRESULT=0x80040527
```

then:

```
20130701.150236 I   12504   QBSDKMsgSetHandler  Request 0 completed successfully.
20130701.150238 E   12504   QBSDKProcessRequest *** INTERNAL ERROR WHEN PROCESSING THE QBXML REQUEST ***.
```

On an InvoiceQuery via QBFC11 using VB.Net2008.

Seems like things are falling apart.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try anything else, reboot the computer running QuickBooks.

We've seen lots of problems with the latest releases of QuickBooks throwing weird errors if the computers aren't rebooted after QuickBooks installs updates.